# REST: Desing pattern for different detalization levels of resource representation

Tags: json, rest, design-patterns

I'm designing REST API for many resources I need to maintain at least 2 representations of the same format (e.g. JSON) which only differ in the amount of data they expose.

For example, I have books, publishers and authors which I'm exposing via REST. So I have 3 collection of resources:`books`, `publishers` and `authors`.
When requesting a book I want it to include minimum information about its authors and publishers - just names, ids and hyperlinks to their full representation.

```
GET /books/12345
200 OK
{
    id: "12345",
    title: "My Book",
    authors: [
        {id:"111", name:"J. Smith", _href:"/authors/111"},
        {id:"222", name:"J.R.R. Tolkien", _href:"/authors/222"}
    ],
    publisher: {id:"333", name:"HarperCollins", _href:"/publishers/333"},
}
```

When user requests, e.g. `/publishers/333` it should get more info about it, not just name and id:

```
{
    id: "333",
    name: "HarperCollins",
    address : { ... },
    contact : { ... },
    logo : { ... }
}
```

In my application I have 3 classes `Book`, `Publisher` and `Author`, where `Book` contain publisher and collection of authors. And I'm using Jackson and Spring MVC to expose all the entities as JSON via REST API.

```
@RequestMapping("/books/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public Book getBook(String id) {
    return getBookById(id);
}

@RequestMapping("/authors/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public Book getAuthor(String id) {
    return getAuthorById(id);
}
```

Now the questions:

- How would I tell the view which fields of which object should be rendered in which case?
- Should I instead split each my entity into two - one for short and another for full representation (e.g. `AuthorReference` and `Author`, `PublisherReference` and `Publisher`).
- Should I prefer composition or generalization if I go with option #2?
- Is there any best practice how to deal with different detalizations of the same entity representation in REST applications?

Comment: Some more ideas (from a consumer/client point of view) here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175355/rest-api-wrapper-class-design-for-lite-object-responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a more standard hypermedia format, such as [HAL](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-05)?

Doing so, it becomes pretty clear that you would have a difference between resources, and links to other resources. For example, it might end up as:

```
GET /books/123
200 OK
{
  "id": "123"
  "title": "My Book"
  "_links": {
     "author": [
       { "href": "/authors/111", "title": "J. Smith" },
       { "href": "/authors/321", "title": "Jules Verne" }
     ],
     "publisher": { "href": "/publishers/123", "title": "Harper Collins" }
  }
}
```

In terms of implementation, I would say you can either:

1. Create custom DTO classes for each resource representation, along the lines of:

   ```
    public class BookDto {
        @JsonProperty(value="_links")
        public LinkCollection getLinks() { }

        public String getTitle() { }
    }
   ```
2. Use the same classes, but use filters to modify the objects before Jackson serializes, and use some combination of @JsonProperty/@JsonIgnore.

Comment: As for @JsonProperty/@JsonIgnore I don't want to pollute my domain model classes with the view specific annotations, moreover the difference between a short and full representations is more than just a different set of properties exposed. E.g. the short representation need to have additional `_href` property that is neither in the full representation nor in the domain object itself. And there are other similar cases that are tricky (if possible) to implement via annotations only.

Comment: DTO is an option, yes, but only in case I go with splitting an entity and its reference, which is what you suggest as I understand. But may be there is another way how to do it without introducing more classes? Since I'm using custom serializers it gives me an opportunity to make a decision which representation to choose at the time a given object is being serialized. I just need to find a nice consistent way to tell my serializer which representation should be created and when.

Comment: I understand your concern regarding additional classes, but most REST advocates emphasize that domain classes and resources often aren't one-to-one mappings. With that assumption, I usually use a DTO suited specifically for the resource. There is some 'duplication', but it avoids having your API being brittle/break due to *domain* changes.

Comment: And if you got the DTO route and are using Hibernate, for a GET that needs to respond w/ a DTO, I typically will use a projection + `setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MyDto.class))` to easily get a populated DTO ready to be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

1/ According to Spring MVC documentation, to serialize your object over HTTP you have to define your own class implementing `HttpMessageConverter<T>` with `T` either `Book`, `Publisher` or `Author`.
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-message-conversion

2/ It is not necessary to split your objects in two. The logic to select what fields you pick up from an `Author` is contained in the `AuthorToHttp implement HttpMessageConverter<Author>`. Just need to develop a `AuthorReferenceToHttp implement HttpMessageConverter<Author>` to use when you want less data to be send over HTTP.

Another solution could be either `AuthorReference extend Author` or `Author extend AuthorReference` on one hand and `AuthorToHttp implement HttpMessageConverter<Author>` with `AuthorReferenceToHttp implement HttpMessageConverter<AuthorReference>` on the other hand to serialize your `Author`.

3/ Inheritance/Generalization is enough. Not necessarily a need for a pattern.

Composite is a wrong choice, you don't need a tree structure. According to circumstances you want either all data about an author - default behavior -, or the main data about an author - "proxied" behavior -. Proxy would be a better choice.

4/ No idea.